# Format dynamic text in a Flash HTML5 Canvas Project

Tags: html, flash, text, htmltext

I am building a simple flash HTML5 canvas project that has recipes.

I would like to load the text into dynamic text fields from variables and format the text with HTML tags.

The text needs to word wrap and have line breaks.

To my frustration I can not seem to make this work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: this.ingredients.text = 'Ingredients:<br>1 - Small banana<br>8 - Strawberries<br> 8 - Grapes"

Comment: I am using a text box on the stage with the instance name ingredients.